# How to increase speed of iterations with nonlinear functions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Let me ask about part of a problem which I have in solving of a nonlinear DE (numerically).
I am working with vectors of length $xN$. I have an initial vector $v$, a given $xN\times xN$ matrix $A$ and a given nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Next, I need to construct the following two-dimensional list of vectors (I do not use here Mathematica's brackets just to simplify notations) using the rule
$$
w_{n,m}[k]=\begin{cases}
v[k], & \text{if } n=0 \text{ or } m=1,\\
w_{n,m-1}[k]+f\Bigl[(A.w_{n-1,m})[k],w_{n-1,m}[k] \Bigr], &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$ 
Here $k=1,\ldots,xN$ are vector indexes, $n=0,\ldots nN$ are iteration numbers, and $m=1,\ldots,tN$ are 'time'-steps. After all $nN$ iterations are done, I have to save the last iteration
$$
u_m[k]=w_{nN,m}[k], \qquad m=1,\ldots,tN, \quad k=1,\ldots,xN,
$$
and I have to redefine the initial condition by the value of the last iteration at the last 'moment of time'
$$
v[k]=u_{tN}[k], \qquad  k=1,\ldots,xN,
$$
and repeat the same procedure to get now values for vectors $u_{tN+m}$, $m=1,\ldots,tN$, and so on until I find all vectors $u_{j}$ for $j=1,\ldots, tN\cdot tS$, for some chosen natural $tS$.

My realization is the following (here the matrix $A$ and the initial $v$ are random, whereas I need a particular; on the other hand, for some $f$ one can have an overflow, thus I use very simple $f$ just to show the slowness even in this case):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
xN = 20;
tN = 50;
tS = 30;
nN = 20;
A = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {xN, xN}];
v = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {xN}];
f[p_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ] := p + r;
rhs[vec_] := rhs[vec] = MapThread[f, {A.vec, vec}];
Do[
    w[n_, m_] := w[n, m] = If[n == 0 || m == 1, v, w[n, m - 1] + rhs[w[n - 1, m]]];
    Do[u[m + (i - 1) tN] = w[nN, m], {m, tN, 1, -1}];
    v = w[nN, tN]; 
    Clear[w], 
{i, 1, tS}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It works, but for $xN=20$ it spends 18 sec, whereas for $xN=30$ almost 40 sec; unfortunately, I need $xN=200$ and less trivial $f$. (Note that the code above is very sensitive to $f$, if $f(p,r)=0.01(p+r)$ then everything is ten times faster, hence something is bad in the code).

Could you suggest me an improvement for the code (I am very newbie in Mathematica)?

Comment: You can try [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) some of your functions.

Comment: Could you advice more precisely?

Comment: @Silvia The numbers early on exceed machine double ranges so `Compile` is not going to be a gain.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You're right! I actually didn't test on OP's `f`, so overlooked that issue... Hopefully OP's true problem will not / can be made not to suffer from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note your iteration rule can be reduced to an explicit formula:

$$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{w}}_{n,m}=\boldsymbol{v}+\sum_{k=2}^m f(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\mathrm{w}}_{n-1,k},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{w}}_{n-1,k})\mathrm{,\;\;(for\;}n>1\mathrm{)}$$

So we can calculate the $n$-th row of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{w}}$ in one time by performing `Accumulate`on a list derived from the $(n-1)$-th row of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{w}}$. By `Nest`-ing the calculation, we get the $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{u}}_m$.

Code is straightforward. Note I increased `xN`, `tN`, `nN`, and used a nonlinear $f(\alpha,\beta):=\exp(-\alpha^2)+\sin(\beta)$ here:

```
uFunc = Compile[{
                 {v, _Real, 1},  {A, _Real, 2},
                 {tN, _Integer}, {nN, _Integer}
                },
                Nest[
                     Accumulate[
                                Join[{v},
                                     Function[{α, β},
                                                    Exp[-α^2] + Sin[β]
                                             ][#.Transpose[A], #] & @ Rest[#]
                                    ]
                               ] &,
                     Table[v, tN], (* 1st row of w *)
                     nN + 1
                    ]
               ]

xN = 200;
tN = 500;
nN = 200;
A = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {xN, xN}];
v = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {xN}];

AbsoluteTiming[uFunc[v, A, tN, nN];][[1]]
```

> 2.44941

Comment: In Table[v,tN] the brackets are missed: Table[v, {tN}].

Comment: @Dmitri They are the same.

Comment: Are you in v10? in v9 and v8 `Table[v, mi]` breaks the code.

Comment: @xzczd I didn't notice that! Compare the first usage information of `Table` in [v10's doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and in [v9's](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v9/ref/Table.html). I think they changed the syntax without notifying it at the top-right corner and it's a doc bug.

Comment: @Silvia Could you please also look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100655/nestlist-inside-compile)? This is a continuation of the question: I need to calculate your code not for tN=500, but say for tN=5, then the last row of the result needs to be saved and considered as a new value for vector v, and so on .. 50 times. I've realised this with a NestedList but I am still looking for an optimisation.