# Nestlist inside Compile

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile

My question is a continuation of [question1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/how-to-increase-speed-of-iterations-with-nonlinear-functions) and [question2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100551/a-quicker-than-outer), but I think it may be considered as a self-contained one.

I am interested to make the following code faster

```
x = Table[-10 + 0.02 (j - 1), {j, 1, 1001}];
func = Compile[{{s, _Real}}, Exp[-Abs[s]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
matr = func[x - #] & /@ x;
vec = 0.24 UnitStep[1 - #^2] & /@ x;
sol = Compile[
        {{v, _Real, 1}, {mA, _Real, 2}, {mc, _Real}, {md, _Real}, 
         {mi, _Integer}, {mj, _Integer}, {mk, _Integer}}, 
        NestList[
            Function[w, 
                Nest[
                      Accumulate[
                         Join[{w}, 
                                Function[{p, r}, mc p (1 - r) - md  r]                                       
                                [#.mA, #] &@Rest[#]
                            ]
                              ]&,
                      Table[w, mi], mj
                      ][[mi]]
                    ], v, mk]];

sol[vec, Transpose[matr], 0.0002, 0.014, 50, 10, 50];
```

It takes 17 sec on my slow laptop and several times faster on the office Mac, but I feel that it can be faster.

In particular, I think  that I lose too much time because of Function-structure after the NestList, I have to use pure functions but I do not know how to distinguish different # (it loook that #1, #2 does not work here).

(Note that you have to pass 'small' values of mc and md, otherwise the process will be even much slower.)

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you examined the compiled code with [`CompilePrint`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1814)?  (That whole Q&A is worth reading carefully.)

Comment: Thanks! No `MainEvaluate`, however, twice `CopyTensor` in the loops. Now it is a big question how to avoid them. Are `Join`, `Accumulate`, `Part` in loops of the compiled code also dangerous?