# For-loop function problem

Tags: functions, infinite-loop

I wrote the following true anomaly function based on a Fortran program that I found in a computational space flight dynamics book. The function uses an iterative method to calculate the true anomaly of and object based on its orbital period and eccentricity.

The real problem is that the function stops working after producing 13,923 data points -- meaning that the argument `simLength` cannot be bigger that 13923. It doesn't crash, it just displays the "Running..." message indefinitely. Is it a problem with memory? Or is it a problem with *Mathematica's* loop functions?

I am using version 10.3.0 and I first noticed the problem by when trying run [3*58944, 58944, 0.8]. I found the exact limit by having the data points exported to a text file and then importing it back and checking the length of the list.

The number of data points that the function should return is determined by the input "simLength" and the local variable "dT" at "kEnd = Round[simLength/dT]". So if dT is set to 10, and want the simLength to be 10,000 I should get 1000 data points in return.

```
trueAnomaly[simLength_, period_, e_] := 
  Module[
    {tp = 0., endPoint = 1.*10^-5, dT = 10., k = 1., kEnd, theta, τ, dE, e0, e1, t},
    kEnd = Round[simLength/dT];
    theta = Table[0, kEnd];
    t = Table[0, kEnd];
    For[k, k <= kEnd, k++,
      t[[k]] = k dT;
      τ = 2 π (t[[k]] - tp)/period;
      dE = .1;
      e0 = .1;
      While[dE > endPoint,
        e1 = e0 - (e0 - e Sin[e0] - τ)/(1. - e Cos[e0]);
        dE = Abs[e1 - e0];
        e0 = e1;];
      theta[[k]] = 2.*ArcTan[Sqrt[(1 + e)/(1 - e)]*Tan[e0/2.]];
      If[theta[[k]] < 0, theta[[k]] = 2.*π + theta[[k]]];];
    Return[{t, theta}];]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.  (You have formatted the code as a "quote.")

Comment: @Bill. `Table[0, 3]` produces `{0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I ran `data = trueAnomaly[150000, 365., .01];` without any problem. I am using V10.3 on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: @Bill. for a closed orbit you must have `0 <= e < 1`. A finite value for period indicates a closed orbit.

Comment: @m_goldberg The syntax of `Table` has been modified silently in v10: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99500/how-to-increase-speed-of-iterations-with-nonlinear-functions/99517#comment273219_99517

Comment: @xzczd. Yeah, that's what I was pointing out.

Comment: I think it would help if you supplied a few more pieces of info. What version of _Mathematica_ are you running? What were the values of the arguments you gave `trueAnomaly` when it failed to complete? I am also confused because if  `n` is passed as the first arg, you code only produces `Round[n/10]` data points. But I also would like the what `period` and `e` were.

Comment: I added extra info to the problem description.

Comment: This is not a problem with memory or with Mathematica's loop functions. The problem is that your code contains a While loop which terminates only when `dE <= endPoint`, a condition which is **never** true for the k=13924 point in `trueAnomaly[3*58944, 58944, 0.8]`. At this point instead of converging to a single fixed value, e1 stabilises on a cycle of 3 values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code implements an infinite loop and therefore running indefinitely is the correct behaviour.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks! I'll just put a limit on how many times the While loop is allowed to run.

Comment: You might want to check out `FixedPoint` as a replacement for the While loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but and extended comment.

I ran your code with some minor modifications without any problems. Here is the code I ran:

```
trueAnomaly[simLength_, period_, e_] := 
  Module[
     {tp = 0., endPoint = 1.*10^-5, dT = 10., k, kEnd, theta, τ, dE, e0, e1, t, a},
    a = Sqrt[(1. + e)/(1. - e)]; (* only compute this once *)
    kEnd = Round[simLength/dT];
    t = Table[0, kEnd];
    theta = Table[0, kEnd];
    For[k = 1, k <= kEnd, k++,
      t[[k]] = k dT;
      τ = 2 π (t[[k]] - tp)/period;
      dE = .1; e0 = .1;
      While[dE > endPoint,
        e1 = e0 - (e0 - e Sin[e0] - τ)/(1. - e Cos[e0]);
        dE = Abs[e1 - e0];
        e0 = e1];
      theta[[k]] = 2.*ArcTan[a*Tan[e0/2.]];
      If[theta[[k]] < 0, theta[[k]] = 2.*π + theta[[k]]]];
    {t, theta}] (* no need for Return *)
```

I was able to evaluate

```
data = trueAnomaly[150000, 365., .01];
```

Comment: Hey, I tried using this code and noticed that since the variable "k" isn't given a starting value, the For loop doesn't actually run, so all that is returned are 2 lists of zeros haha. I set k = 1 and ran into the same problem. But thanks for the tip on calculating "a" first.

Comment: @astroDynamic. Thanks for pointing the typo in my code and also for the adding additional information to your post. Using your new info, I found the problem is not in the number of data points you used, but in the value for `e`. The algorithm appears to fail for `e >= .5`. Unfortunately, I don't have time to investigate further, but my finding should give you some new ideas on where to look for what's going wrong.